# Xpath expression won't select anything

Tags: java, xml, xpath

HI there,
I have an xml that is dynamically generated, from which I want to extract the information..I was using Xpath expressions but found out my xpath expression is not working properly it doesn't select anything.....here's my Java function which executes the xpath expression:

```
public void TraverseClass(NavigationTree parent,String name)
    {
         xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr;

            try {
                expr = xPath.compile("Class[@name=\""+name+"\"]/Class");
                 Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                  NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nodes.getLength());
                    for(int i=0;i<=nodes.getLength()-1;i++)
                    {
                        Node first=nodes.item(i);
                        Element node=(Element)first;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Found Classes inside "+name+" " +node.getAttribute("name"));
                        parent.foundClass(node.getAttribute("name"));
                    //Interfaces[i]=node.getAttribute("name");

                    }
                    expr = xPath.compile("Class[@name=\""+name+"\"]/Interfaces");
                     result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                     nodes = (NodeList) result;

                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nodes.getLength());
                        for(int i=0;i<=nodes.getLength()-1;i++)
                        {
                            Node first=nodes.item(i);
                            Element node=(Element)first;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Found Interfaces inside "+name+" "+node.getAttribute("name"));
                            parent.foundInterface(node.getAttribute("name"));
                        //Interfaces[i]=node.getAttribute("name");

                        }
                        expr = xPath.compile("Class[@name=\""+name+"\"]/Method");
                         result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                         nodes = (NodeList) result;

                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nodes.getLength());
                            for(int i=0;i<=nodes.getLength()-1;i++)
                            {
                                Node first=nodes.item(i);
                                Element node=(Element)first;
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Found Methods inside "+name+" "+node.getAttribute("name"));
                                parent.foundMethod(node.getAttribute("name"));
                            //Interfaces[i]=node.getAttribute("name");

                            }


            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error: "+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"going one step back in Class "+name);
            parent.goOneStepBack();
    }
```

Now the xml file I am trying to parse is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<program>
 <Interface modifier="public" name="interface1">
  <ParentInterface> i1</ParentInterface>
  <ParentInterface> i2</ParentInterface>
  <ParentInterface> i3</ParentInterface>
  <Field modifier="" type="int" name="a,b,c">
  </Field>
  <Interface modifier="public" name="one">
   <ParentInterface> two</ParentInterface>
  </Interface>
  <Class modifier="public" name="three"> 
   <Parent>four</Parent> 
  </Class>
  <Method modifier="" type="void" name="foo1">
   <FormalParameter >
   </FormalParameter> 
  </Method>
 </Interface>
 <Class modifier="" name="FrontPAge"> 
  <Parent>JFrame</Parent> 
  <Field modifier="public" type="int" name="a,b,c">
  </Field>
  <Field modifier="" type="int" name="arr[]">
  </Field>
  <Field modifier="" type="int" name="arr2[]">
  </Field>
  <Field modifier="" type="int" name="num[]">
  </Field>
  <Field modifier="" type="FrontPAge" name="fp">
  </Field>
  <Constructor modifier="public" name="FRontPage">
   <FormalParameter >
   </FormalParameter> 
   <Statement> <![CDATA[System.out.println("It is a constructor")]]></Statement>
  </Constructor>
  <Method modifier="publicstatic" type="void" name="main">
   <FormalParameter modifier="" type="String[]" var_name="args" >
   </FormalParameter> 
   <Field modifier="" type="int" name="x,y,z">
   </Field>
   <Field modifier="" type="int" name="sum[]">
   </Field>
   <For>
    <Itr_Var type="int">x</Itr_Var>
    <Collection><![CDATA[num]]></Collection>
    <Statement> <![CDATA[sum+=x]]></Statement>
   </For>
   <Interface modifier="public" name="qqq">
    <ParentInterface> www</ParentInterface>
   </Interface>
   <Statement> <![CDATA[System.out.println("Runnable is gonna start")]]></Statement>
   <Class name="Runnable">
    <Method modifier="public" type="void" name="run">
     <FormalParameter >
     </FormalParameter> 
     <Statement> <![CDATA[System.out.println("Hello")]]></Statement>
    </Method>
   </Class>
   <Statement> <![CDATA[EventQueue.invokeLater(newRunnable(){publicvoidrun()  {System.out.println("Hello");}})]]></Statement>
   <Statement> <![CDATA[System.out.println("Runnable Ends Here")]]></Statement>
   <Statement> <![CDATA[c=b+d]]></Statement>
   <Statement> <![CDATA[a=b+c]]></Statement>
  </Method>
  <Class modifier="" name="nested"> 
  </Class>
  <Interface modifier="public" name="xxx">
   <ParentInterface> yyy</ParentInterface>
  </Interface>
 </Class>
</program>
```

Information: The name parameter of java function contains the name of one highest level classes,i.e descendants of root element which may futrther contain other classes/interfaces/methods...

Question:  My problem is the expression I am using `Class[@name=<ClassName>]/Class` should select all the classes from the xml,exclude everything other than select the class with the name and then select all the child classes of that class...same thing goes with the interfaces and methods...but it doesn't work at all!!!!....none of the expressions match anything....

I can't rely on absolute paths much because xml is generated dynamically from source codes and thus content of xml except for the root element too are subjected to change

Comment: You forgot to tell us exactly which nodes of the provided XML document you want to select? Please, do so, or your question isn't really a question and is likely to be closed/deleted. Not to speak that people are guessing and the answers you receive won't be either timely or accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression selects all *nested* classes (there is only one in your sample document: class "FrontPAge" has a nested class:

```
//Class/Class
```

or with name attribute

```
//Class[@name="FrontPAge"]/Class
```

Your expression *should* work, if you evaluate the root node but not the document (in Line 8). If you want to evaluate on the document, the first element is `<program>` and you'd have to say

```
program/Class[@name=\"" + name + "\"]/Class
```

---

*Off the records:* I used [this online xpath evaluator](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx) to verify the expressions. Just copy the sample document to the text field and play with XPath expressions

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to start your xpath expressions with `program` as it is the root element

e.g:

```
expr = xPath.compile("program/Class[@name=\""+name+"\"]/Interfaces")
```

I haven't tested this out myself, but it's worth a try :)

Comment: `*/` also works for the root element. This is the way we normally do our xpaths.

Comment: I don't understand this but when I changed my expression to

 expr = xPath.compile("program//Class[@name=\""+name+"\"]/Interface");

it worked at least for this xml....Now as I interpret this it selects all the descendants of program and selects the class element with the given name and then selects all the interfaces of that class.....but I suspect it will fail when there are two high level classes and both contains an interface with the same nameany other suggestion for better XPath expression??

Comment: In this case you can get the node parent node you want using xpath, and then perform your xpath queries relative to it. For example: `expr.evaluate(myNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);`. This way `myNode` can come from a NodeList.